# Solution has inconsistent use of units?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, dimensional-analysis

I am working on the following problem:

> In recitation a population model was studied in which the natural growth rate of the population of oryx was a constant $k > 0$, so that for small time intervals $\Delta t$ the population change $x(t + \Delta t) − x(t)$ is well approx­imated by $kx(t)\Delta t$. (You also studied the effect of hunting them, but in this problem we will leave that aside.) Measure time in years and the population in kilo-oryx (ko).
>
> A mysterious virus infects the oryxes of the Tana River area in Kenya, which causes the growth rate to decrease as time goes on according to the formula $k(t) = \dfrac{k_0}{(a + t)^2}$ for $t \ge 0$, where $a$ and $k_0$ are certain positive constants.
>
> (a) What are the units of the constant $a$ in “$a + t$,” and of the constant $k_0$?

The [problem set](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-i-first-order-differential-equations/basic-de-and-separable-equations/MIT18_03SCF11_ps1_II_s1s.pdf) gives the following solution to a):

> The growth rate $k(t)$ has units years$^{−1}$ (so that $k(t)x(t)\Delta t$ has the same units as $x(t)$). The variable $t$ has units years, so the $a$ added to it must have the same units, and $k_0$ must have units years in order for the units of the fraction to work out.

The part about $a$ and $t$ having the same units makes sense. However, I have doubts about the correctness of this solution. The solution itself says that $k(t)$ has units years$^{−1}$. If $k_0 = k(0)$ ($k(t)$ where $t = 0$), then is it not inconsistent to then say it has units years in the equation $k(t) = \dfrac{k_0}{(a + t)^2}$? Should it not still have units years$^{−1}$?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: In fact $k_0$ and $a$ should have units of years in order to get $\frac{k_0}{(a+t)^2}$ to have units of years$^{-1}$.  Note the denominator is squared.

Comment: @hardmath I agree with that, but is it not inconsistent for the reasons I described: $k_0 = k(0)$ is just $k(t = 0)$, and we know that $k(t)$ has units years$^-1$? So how can we say that $k(t)$ has units years$^{-1}$ and $k_0$ has units years? Is this not inconsistent, since they are the same thing, just with different values for $t$?

Comment: Clearly $k(0)$ is $k_0/a^2$, not $k_0$.

Comment: @hardmath So $k(t)$ has units years$^{-1}$ only for $t > 0$? Otherwise, it has units years?

Comment: I don't follow your argument.  $k(t)$ should have by definition units years$^{-1}$ for all time $t$.  My point is that if you substitute $t=0$ into the formula $k(t) = k_0/(a+t)^2$, then you get $k(0)$.  The claim that $k(0)=k_0$ is not justified by repeating that this is so.

Comment: @hardmath Oh ok, I see. So you agree with Alphacapture's answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$k_0\neq k(t)|_{t=0}.$

First, one can check this by plugging in 0 into the expression:

$k(0)=\frac{k_0}{a^2}\neq k_0.$

So we conclude that $k_0$ does not represent $k$ at $t=0.$  $k_0$ can be understood as a constant that does not have any "meaning" by itself but rather as a constant used to create a formula, attached to whatever units make the formula work.

I am not knowledgeable at all about this, but perhaps a similar example would be the [Gravitational Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant).